# Error reading csv file in Azure HDInsight Blob Store.

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

Jupyter note book gives the following error.
u'Path does not exist: wasb://spk123-2018@dreamcatcher.blob.core.windows.net/data/raw-flight-data.csv;
The csv file does exist in the blob store of Azure HDInsight

Answer (score 0):

What is the command you are doing in Jupyter?

Check for a couple of two problems:
1. The file actually doesn't exist. You can check that by going into Azure portal -> storage account and checking if this container has the file.
2. You didn't connect the storage account to the cluster when you created the cluster.